# Grease Pencil colour gets darker everytime I draw

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm very new to Blender Grease Pencil, and I've been having a problem where every time I do a new stroke, the drawings I already have gets darker. I was wondering why that is. Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/_1PPtgtY838) to show what I mean.